# HIVE Creating Table not null

Tags: hadoop, db2, hive, apache-pig

this is my query in DB2 Database:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE                                                 
      (COD_SOC              CHAR(5)  NOT NULL);
```

Is possible reproduce the 'NOT NULL' in HIVE?
What about PIG?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it is not possible at this time.  It would be very difficult for Hive to enforce column constraints.

Comment: Has this behavior changed recently in any Hive version ?

Comment: I don't know if it has changed recently

Answer (score 1):

With Hive 3.0, you can have `DEFAULT` Constraints on the hive table

Refer 
1. https://www.adaltas.com/en/2019/07/25/hive-3-features-tips-tricks/
2. https://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/what-is-new-in-apache-hive-30